# Does Foundry Data Connection support SFTP sources?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-data-connection

When using Data Connection, can I ingest files into Foundry from an SFTP (SSH File Transfer Protocol, not FTPS) source?

Answer (score 0):

Data Connection doesn't support STFP out of the box. However, there is a custom source.

Ask your Palantir team to install it.